# Sound plays on emulator but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation

I was doing a tutorial and I tested this code, it works when I run on the emulator but when I test on the iPhone it can't.
I debugged and he makes no mistake, just doesn't play the sound.

```swift
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

 var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

 @IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

   playSound(tag: sender.tag)

 }

 func playSound(tag: Int) {

   let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note\(tag)", withExtension: "wav")
   do {
      audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
   } catch {
      print(error)
   }

   audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
   audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
   audioPlayer.play()
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the phone is unmuted?

Comment: Of course I confirmed that and it wasn't @DávidPásztor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)` before play audio